# How can I check some classes or packages only with animal-sniffer-maven-plugin?

Tags: maven, animal-sniffer

With following configuration, how can I make it sure to check against the signature for limited classes and packages?

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>animal-sniffer-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>check</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <signature>
        </signature>
        <!-- How can I select packages/classes to check? -->
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract those packages in separate sub-modules, and only use the plugin in those modules.